# dynamic table in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic

i have a declared a table :

```
DECLARE @V_TABLE (ROW_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), CLIENTKEY, UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

i have tried to use this table in a piece of dynamic sql

```
SET @SQL = ' INSERT INTO #CLIENTTABLE ( CLIENTKEY )
              (SELECT CLIENTKEY FROM '+ @V_TABLE  +')'
```

the code keeps asking me to declare @v_table
how can i use this table in the dynamic sql

Comment: Why do you need dynamic SQL at all? If you really do need dynamic SQL could you use a local temporary table instead of a table variable?

Answer (score 0):

In your query @V_TABLE is a table variable and not a string variable containing the name of the table. Hence, if the query is prepared like so, it should work.

```
SET @SQL = ' INSERT INTO #CLIENTTABLE ( CLIENTKEY )
              (SELECT CLIENTKEY FROM @V_TABLE')'
```